# Interactive Shutdown program displays help page?

Tags: python

I'm in a python programming course and my task using os.system command is to initiate a check disk and then a shutdown while querying the user for time till shutdown and to input a display message upon shutdown. After running this I just get the help page for shutdown

Code:

```
import os

d = input("Seconds before shutdown?")
m = input("Message before shutdown?")

shutdown = "shutdown /r /t /c" + (m) + "/t" + (d)

os.system(shutdown)
```

Comment: You can print(shutdown) to see exactly what you're passing `os.system()`. The problem may be you need a space character separating the `/c` and `/t` from the numeric values that go with them. Also the documentation for the `shutdown` command uses `-` instead of `/` before the option letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `/t` twice and the first one is not followed by the expected argument (the number of seconds until shutdown)
Try this:

```
shutdown = 'shutdown /r /t {0} /c "{1}"'.format(d,m)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. After the first comment I went through to change forward slashes to hyphens and add spaces when I noticed the double t. A soon as I removed it, it worked perfectly! Thanks again